# JPA each time findBy create new object

Tags: java, spring-boot, object, jpa

I am developing spring boot application with login for multiple users. After login, I search for `Person` which is related `OneToOne` with `User` the issue is when I log out and login again  `Person person = personService.findByUser(user);` search again for that person found it and create new object person which have `null` values for his properties I need to not create new object person and to use already created in the last login with that user.I am quite lost, I am not sure if I need to use Singleton here.

```
person = personService.findByUser(currentUser);
person.setTransientProperty(value)
person.getTransientProperty() # Not null
```

> Log out

> Login again

```
person = personService.findByUser(currentUser);
person.getTransientProperty() #  null
```

Comment: Your Person Entity is read through, managed and so cached by the persistence context. You will only get the same instance of that Person, with the transient values set, if you read it in from the same persistence context. That won't likely be possible across threads when the container controls the context, and EntityManagers are not thread safe anyway, so you might want to switch strategies and cache it in a static/VM level cache that you create and control.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you give me some example article to take a look how I need to implement it this is beyond my experience and knowledge

Comment: Actually `TransientProperty` is a thread and I can't save it to database

Comment: I figured by the naming, and that is why you need to cache it in the VM. There are many different ways to cache things - a simple Map in a static or a singleton class, or a google cache instance - and many tutorials on using them. Your use case might require determining when to clear that cache; when the 'value' is no longer valid, or when the Person instance itself needs to be refreshed from the database should it have been changed or deleted since it was last read into the cache.

Comment: I will search online, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using in service

> @Transactional(readOnly = true)

If we use @Transactional(readOnly = true) to a method which is performing create or update operation then we will not have newly created or updated record into the database but we will have the response data.